# Twitter Tweet-button with opengraph support? Is it possible?

Tags: twitter, facebook-opengraph

I've already added the [Facebook like-button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/), the [Google +1 button](http://code.google.com/apis/+1button/) and now i'm adding the [Twitter Tweet button](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button) but noticed that it doesn't make use of any the opengraph metatags i've embedded in the `<head>` of my page while facebook and google do.

How can i make the Tweet Button use the data from my OpenGraph metatags so i don't need to add redundant data to my page just to get the tweet button to work correctly?

Comment: I'm interested in this question too. I think amazon did a quite good job on the twitter integration . See http://twitter.com/#!/amazon/status/169491158962143232 . I couldn't figure out how that rich data is extracted from the amazon page yet. maybe schema.org ?

Answer (score 1):

Currently Twitter doesn't support any kind of tags . See https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1244 . However you can add a picture and location through the media API

```
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update_with_media
```

There are some kind of "automatic" integration but only for big players such amazon.com , youtube.com etc ... Try to tweet a link with any amazon product and the tweet will automatically get populated with additional info such a picture, add to cart button etc .